# Does this adverb prepositional phrase modify the adverb, or vice versa?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

The McGraw Hill Handbook of English Grammar and Usage (pg. 42) gives "We got there late in the evening" as an example of an adverb prepositional phrase ('in the evening') modifying an adverb ('late'). This seems wrong to me. To my mind 'late in the evening' means that we have a period we call the evening--8pm to 11pm, say--and we got there at the late end of that period--say, 10.30. Which means 'late' specifies a particular part of 'in the evening'--ie., modifies it--making it an adverb to 'in the evening', not the other way around. After all, 'we got there late in the evening' doesn't necessarily mean we were 'late', in the sense of 'not on time', at all.

Whereas if we said "We got there late, in the evening" we would mean we were late, and also that it was in the evening--in which case 'late' and 'in the evening' both are adverbs to 'got'. Or we could say 'We got there in the evening--late." This has a slightly different emphasis, but 'in the evening' and 'late' are still adverbs to 'got'.

Is there some way of determining what the adverbs modify without arguing about meaning?

NB. This question is similiar, but NOT the same, as my question "Reliable test for whether PP is an adverb PP or adjective PP"

There I was asking about distinguishing adverb PPs and Adjective PPs. But here, the PP is an adverb either way, so the question of tests is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with you. I would also tend to consider "late in the evening" as a whole an adverbial phrase in its own, which could be (or not) the same as "in the late evening"  where "late" is clearly an adjective.

Comment: "in the late evening"..ah, interesting. We could also say "in the evening late", although that's a bit of a poetic usage. So 'late' can move around. But if we set off 'late' with commas, it can still move around-- 'we got there late, in the evening'-'in the evening, late'-and I guess the commas make 'late' and 'in the evening' parallel adverbs.